# PHP - json_encode multiple arrays with same values count

Tags: php, json, arrays

I need to encode three php arrays that all have the same amount of values. From there it has to be json_encoded.

```
Array ( [0] => Title1
        [1] => 320 KB/s 5.0 MB 1:24
        [2] => http://www.example.com/Title1.mp3 )

Array ( [0] => Title2
        [1] => 120 KB/s 2.8 MB 3:29
        [2] => http://www.example.com/Title2.mp3 )

Array ( [0] => Title3
        [1] => 250 KB/s 8.5 MB 4:59
        [2] => http://www.example.com/Title3.mp3 )
```

The json needs to be a json array like the example below.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "link": "http://www.example.com/Title1.mp3",
            "metadata": "320 KB/s 5.0 MB 1:24",
            "title": "Title1"
        },
        {
            "link": "http://www.example.com/Title2.mp3",
            "metadata": "120 KB/s 2.8 MB 3:29",
            "title": "Title2"
        },
        {
            "link": "http://www.example.com/Title3.mp3",
            "metadata": "250 KB/s 8.5 MB 4:59",
            "title": "Title3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the issue that you're facing?

Comment: Have you found [json_encode](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) helpful here?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the proper keys for your values in the JSON you will need to define those in your arrays that you have now. Something like this would work:

```
$joinedArrays = array($array1, $array2, $array3);

$JSONarray = array();
foreach($joinedArrays as $array){
    $JSONarray[] = array("title" => $array[0], "metadata" => $array[1], 
        "link" => $array[2]);
}

echo json_encode($JSONarray);
```

So first you compile all of the arrays that you have into one array and then in a foreach loop you create a new associative array with the proper keys and values and add that in as a new value in the `$JSONarray`, thereby creating a multidimensional array. Once you have all of your arrays parsed into new associative arrays, you can run `json_encode($JSONarray);` to get out a JSON formatted in the style that you have asked for.

If you don't compile the information into an associative array first, you will get out a JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    result: 
        {
            0:"Title1", 
            1:"320 KB/s 5.0 MB 1:24", 
            2:"http://www.example.com/Title1.mp3"
        },
        {
            0:"Title2", 
            1:"120 KB/s 2.8 MB 3:29", 
            2:"http://www.example.com/Title2.mp3"
        },
        {
            0:"Title3", 
            1:"250 KB/s 8.5 MB 4:59",
            2:"http://www.example.com/Title3.mp3"
        }
]
```

Comment: @user2936213 Actually, it does work. [Here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/dbf-9hr) is an example

Comment: Yeah but this array is haveing index also  `[0] [1] [2]`. with this it gives error.

Comment: @user2936213 True, before the `json_encode()` `$JSONarray` does have keys `[0] [1] [2]` for the arrays inside of it, but `json_encode()` handles this just fine and gives the proper JSON objects requested by the OP

Answer (score 0):

You could just add each array to a new, multidimensional array like this:

```
$all_data = array();
$all_data[] = $first_array;
$all_data[] = $second_array;
$all_data[] = $third_array;

$json = json_encode($all_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this so i get your resulted json response like that hop you want that too

```
<?php
$arr1[] = array('title'=>'one','value'=>'one');
$arr1[] = array('title'=>'two','value'=>'two');
$arr1[] = array('title'=>'three','value'=>'three');
$arr['result'] = $arr1;

echo '<pre>';print_r(json_encode($arr));
```